# Using an Alias in a joined Subquery OR joining only one row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

so I've been trying to get a query to work for half an hour now and I'm getting desperate. The problem is that I want to join a table to my query that I generate in a subquery. The subquery was supposed to look as follows:

```
left join   (select      ACCN.*, 
                         ROW_NUMBER() over (order by   
                                            case 
                                              when sysdate between ACCN.BDate and ACCN.EDate then 0 
                                              else 1 
                                            end, ACCN.EDate desc) as CNT
                          from        AccountContracts ACCN
                          where       ACCN.AccId = ACC.Id
                          order by    case
                                        when sysdate between ACCN.BDate and ACCN.EDate then 0
                                        else 1
                                      end, ACCN.EDate desc) ACN on ACN.CNT = 1
```

The idea here is that, while one account can be connected to multiple contracts, I only want to show either the active contract (`sysdate between ACCN.AcnBDate and ACCN.AcnEDate`) or the one that has expired most recently. Therefore, I choose the relevant contracts, order them accordingly, and in the end, I only take the first one into account.

However, this doesn't work because I can't reference the Alias `ACC` within the subquery. I could, of course, move the `where`-clause to the `on`-clause, but in that case, the other condition would fail to produce the expected result.

So I either need to be able to reference the Alias in my subquery, choose only the row with the lowest `CNT` in my `on`-clause, or think of a different, better solution (which might very well exist).

Can somebody help with this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: show sample data from your table.

Comment: what do you mean, specifically?

Comment: Show some data rows for different columns involved.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the tables right now as I just left work. I'll try to explain a few specifics. 

The table `AccountContracts` is abbreviated with `ACCN` here. Its column `AccId` is connected to the `Accounts`-table through that table's primary key `Id`. Every contract is connected to an account. 

`ACCN.BDate` and `ACCN.EDate` are timestamps, obviously. More fields aren't really involved here. The `Accounts`-table is referenced in the query that's hierarchically above the one I gave.

Comment: It's hard to comment based on unfinished query and non-existing data, but you may try to change inline view to use partition by accid, remove accn.accid = acc.id, remove order by from the inline view because you do not need it, and join using 'on acn.accid = acc.id where acn.cnt = 1'. You may also try to change that inline view into exists clause. Btw. why are you using outer join here?

Comment: And why not joining `account` with `accountcontracts` and then using analytic function to filter the results?

Answer (score 0):

1. Select current contracts.
2. Select most recent contracts for accounts that do not have current contracts.
3. UNION these two lists.

Try this:

```sql
-- Get all current contracts
;WITH current_contracts AS (
        SELECT       ACCN.AccId
                    ,ACCN.ContractId -- Replace with relevant column name
        FROM         AccountContracts ACCN
        WHERE sysdate BETWEEN ACCN.BDate AND ACCN.EDate
),
recent_contracts AS (
        SELECT       ACCN.AccId
                    ,ACCN.ContractId
        FROM        AccountContracts ACCN
        WHERE
        -- Exclude current_contracts
        NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM current_contracts c
                WHERE ACCN.AccId = c.AccId
        )
        -- Most recent contracts
        AND ACCN.Edate = (
                            SELECT MAX(EDate)
                            FROM AccountContracts m
                            WHERE m.AccId = ACCN.AccId
                            )

        UNION

        SELECT  AccId
               ,ContractId
        FROM current_contracts
)

SELECT Acc.Id, r.AccId, r.ContractId
FROM leftTable ACC
LEFT JOIN recent_contracts r
    ON ACC.Id = r.AccId

;
```